# Validate inlines based on another inlines in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a `Game` object which is linked to `PeriodScore`, which is an object with score for each team in each quarter, and `PlayerBoxscore` which is an object with all stats of a `Player` in given `Game`.

I want to make sure that sum of points (for each team) in `PeriodScore` is the same as sum of points of all `PlayerBoxscores` (in each team), and raise a `ValidateError` (prevent them from saving) if they're not equal.

I know how to sum them up individually by creating a `BaseInlineFormSet` for each `inline` but I don't know how or where to compare them with each other.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you could do it that way. They have no knowledge of each other really. I think the best spot for this would be either at the point where all forms are valid in the view or somewhere right before the Game object is saved. I think the former is the better choice.